# Anonymous Overriding HashSet hashCode

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use a `HashSet` to remove the duplicates from a list of `ApplicationInfo` objects and I'm trying to use more advanced ways to accomplish this than the good old loop and compare.

I've been recently learning about the anonymous abilities in Java and I'm trying to apply that here but I'm stuck. From what I understand, `equals()` simply uses the `hashCode()` method to determine equality and from what I could gather I would only need to override the `hashCode()` method.

Within the `ApplicationInfo` object is a field called `packageName`, a string, which is the ONLY field I want the `HashSet` to compare and exclude any duplicates.

Since I'm new to Java, I'd love some help understanding if I'm understanding this right and either way, how to do this. I realize I could extend `HashSet` and do it that way but I want to try this Anonymous deal so I learn something.

If I have a HashSet containing ApplicationInfo objects, how do I return a hashCode based on the packageName field?

```
//Help me fix the below idea please
HashSet<ApplicationInfo> hs = new HashSet<ApplicationInfo>() {
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            // How do I do this sort of thing
            return this.packageName.hashCode();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately `HashSet` doesn't allow you to use custom equality/hash comparisons. Your attempt is overriding the `hashCode` of the *set* rather than each *item* in the set.

If the package name is *always* an appropriate equality indicator, you can override `hashCode` and `equals` in `ApplicationInfo` itself. Otherwise, I think your best bet is to probably to create a `HashMap<String, ApplicationInfo>` mapping the name to package. Assuming it doesn't matter which package you end up with for a particular name, you can just loop:

```
Map<String, ApplicationInfo> nameMap = new HashMap<String, ApplicationInfo>();
for (ApplicationInfo pkg : packages) {
    nameMap.put(pkg.packageName, pkg);
}
```

Comment: I believe you meant ApplicationInfo pkg : packages

Comment: @lukas: Thanks. Blame the influence of C# :)

Comment: Can't seem to edit my comment. At any rate, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `this` is actually the instance of an anonymous class, not an `ApplicationInfo` object. And you won't get what you want that way either.

Why don't you use a `HashMap< String, ApplicationInfo >` instead, and index it by `packageName`?